# Which columns should be indexed in Azure search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Help me understand the concept a little bit,

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-an-index):

> In Azure Cognitive Search, a search index is your searchable content

If I have to make entire SQL table searchable then does it mean all the columns should be defined as indexable?

Comment: The answer depends entirely on what your db schema/table-design is - and you haven't shared it with us, so I'm curious how you expect us to tell you which of your columns should be indexed or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I have to make entire SQL table searchable then does it mean all
> the columns should be defined as indexable?

Technically yes, you would need to make all columns indexable (searchable) caveat being the field data type supports searching (currently `Edm.String` and `Collection(Edm.String)`).

In fact, Azure Search does not even allow you to set a field as searchable if the data type of such field is not either `Edm.String` or `Collection(Edm.String)`.

You should also identify the columns on which you would want to filter the data (typically columns containing boolean, date/time or numerical data) and set `filterable` property as true for those columns.

You should do this exercise to keep your index size small.

Please see this link for more details on index fields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index#-field-definitions-.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav-Mantri , Can you please take a look at Can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76682830/filtering-on-azure-search-index-not-working which seems to be a similar question which is on the filtering subject.  If you have already seen it, it wouldn't have worked. I have edited the question to make it fully reproducible.

Comment: Pleasure meeting again. Thanks I seem to be receiving quality responses from you for more than a decade now.:-)